# Mouseover on a li list to change an image, but cannot catch up

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.active-bean-bag ul li.bean-bag-image').mouseover(function() {
        var activeBeanBag = 'menu-' + $(this).attr("id");
        $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeOut(function(){
                $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').attr("src", '/skins/template/customer/images/'+activeBeanBag+'.png');
                $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').fadeIn();
        });
});
```

});

However when you move over the li options quickly to get to the one you want it does not catch up and shows incorrect image

thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use URL-shorteners, Stack Overflow isn't charging you per-character, and we like to know where we're going when we click a link.

Comment: Its a dev site and i dont want it coming up on google results.

Comment: It won't, all links have `rel="nofollow"` to prevent using Stack Overflow as a means to increase Google ranking.

Comment: not entirely true @DavidThomas I have (somehow) managed to have google link back to a site I was having trouble with from stackoverflow. This may have since been fixed but I understand the OPs concern

Comment: I found out why my link was crawled @DavidThomas - basically I put my link inline in the text and not as a true link (google obviously searches for http in text also)

Comment: @Paul: nice catch! And yet another good reason to use *real* links, not just text. Which is pretty cool. =D

Comment: well it does depend on if you want the google backlink or not @DavidThomas. Should probably be flagged to stackoverflow admins as we can adversely impact their seo (highly unlikely but possible) by backlinking to low quality (relatively speaking) content

Answer (score 1):

Use the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function first. This cancels out any queued animations.

```
$('.selector').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
```

EDIT:: Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.active-bean-bag ul li.bean-bag-image').mouseover(function() {
        var activeBeanBag = 'menu-' + $(this).attr("id");
        $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){
                $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').attr("src", '/skins/template/customer/images/'+activeBeanBag+'.png');
                $('.active-bean-bag img.menu-image').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        });
});
```

Comment: I just tested again this morning and still jumping..... i updated the code above - is that correct? it seems to fadeout old image, fadein old image fadein new image rather than fadeout old image and fadein new image - also is there anyway to preload the new image before the effect?

Comment: That one seems to make everything unresponsive and crashes firefox :)

Comment: @1Line well put it on fiddle, its free and easy to use!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hJ2bL/3/ - seems ok, but think because jsfiddle cached images - it just seems a prob the 1st time you hover though so was its loaded they all work fine but the initial time you use it is the problem - is there a way to wait until its loaded before fadein?

Comment: any ideas on this? i think maybe needs to preload before fadein maybe?

Comment: @1Line yeah, looks like that is the problem, try preloading all the images first

Comment: @1Line look for a javascript preloader plugin, it'l be easier